# Can similar almost same onClick events combined in one dynamic onClick function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

My project is: when people click a `<button>` or `<li>` among a list of section, test, and practice etc. Each click will render a presentational component. My question is whether there is a solution to simplify my code as below.

```
    createSection = () => {
this.setState({
  sectionVisilibity: !this.state.sectionVisilibity
})
```

}

```
    createPractice = () => {
this.setState({
  practiceVisilibity: !this.state.practiceVisilibity
})
}
```

my initialstate is like this

```
    sectionVisilibity:false,
    practiceVisilibity:false,
```

And, the structure of state is

```
this.state={ 
          .....,
          sections:[
             sec1:{name:'',description:''},
             sec2:{...}
           ]
    }
```

My button group is like this

```
const BtnGroup = ({ createSection, createPractice }) => (
  <ul>
    <li onClick={createSection}>Section</li>
    <li onClick={createPractice}>Practice</li>
    <li onClick={createSubSec}>Subsection</li>
    <li onClick={createDownload}>Download</li>
    <li onClick={createTest}>Test</li> 
  </ul>
)
```

Are there a way I can write like

```
createComponent=()=> {
 //conditionally decide the click action by click event
 //The thing I confused about is I did not pass any event here, but the click is work. It can change the flag between true and false.  
}
```

Therefore, could anyone know how to grab value like multiple input I can use attribute  to setState. How about onClick?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple solution for this kind of problem. 
the basic problem here is how to pass parameters to a onClick function.

what i do in this kind of scenario is to use data attributes.

```
    handleClick(ev){
       const type = ev.target.dataset.clickType;
       // switch on type and you got the solution

    }


     const BtnGroup = ({ handleClick }) => (
             <ul>
                    <li data-click-type="session" onClick={handleClick}>Section</li>
                    <li data-click-type="practice" onClick={handleClick}>Practice</li>
                    <li data-click-type="subsection" onClick={handleClick}>Subsection</li>
                    <li data-click-type="download" onClick={handleClick}>Download</li>
                    <li data-click-type="test" onClick={handleClick}>Test</li> 
            </ul>
                )
```

if there is any click action that you want to map to the same handler . you just have to add the same `data-click-type ="attribute"`

in some cases you need to pass the entire object as an argument. that can 
also be achieved by using JSON.stringify`(ob)

also you are not creating any dynamic functions inside `onClick` which makes it more efficient.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much. I don't know the dataset can be powerful like this.

Comment: @Nannnnnnn yes dataset has solved my biggest problem in react,  passing variables to eventHandlers :) cheers and happy coding. and you can always mark my answer as accepted answer :D

Comment: Thanks for reminder~ I am pretty new to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could in theory do some conditional logic on the event, but I don't think you want to do that.

Try something like:

```
    <li onClick={() => createComponent('practice')}>Practice</li>
```

Comment: What the pain part of writing that way?

Comment: Mostly you'd have to inspect the event to determine which `<li>` element was clicked and distinguish between them somehow.  Any such code would be highly brittle - subject to stop working if you changed something.  I would think some variant of an anonymous arrow function would be easier to read.

Comment: When you say variant of an anonymous arrow function, is it the one you just wrote above? :)

Answer (score 0):

There is two another way to do that.
First is make an object of array of your state and then in same order set your li tags in which buttons are present. And on click send index also so that on the basis of index you can change state.
Second is same take your state in object array and on click send name also like the above answer. And in your function you can use seitch case or if else condition which button has beej clicked by the name.

```
this.state = {
  data: [
          {createSection:false},
          {createBlock:false}
        ]
}

onClick(e,index,propertyName){
  let data = this.state.data;
  data[index].propertyName = true;
  this.setState({data:data});
}

<li key={index}> <button onClick 
 {(e)=>this.onClick(e,index,'createSection')}> Create Section </button> 
</li>
<li key={index}> <button onClick=
 {(e)=>this.onClick(e,index,'CreateBlock')}> Create Section </button> 
</li>
```

Keep that in mind that button order must be same as states.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry, I confused about the object array part. Could you give some practical example? Besides, there are also other initial state related to the will-rendered component like section's further structure is this.state={sections:[{sectionName:'', color: '' }]etc.

Comment: i wound not recommend this solution, because you are creating dynamic functions on click which will be created on every re render.

Comment: @chauhanamit you are defining an anonymous function inside the onClick handler. which will be created everytime the render function is executed. that means any change in state or props will case a render and a new function is created every time. which is very inefficient. it takes memory and is slow in execution. yhats why you define function once refer to it again and again whenever to be used